# Custom log level log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to figure out how to keep my application logging level to debug except some packages that I want to set to error, for example:

`DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Sending coordinator request for group xxx to broker aaa:1067 (id: -1 rack: null)`

This is the log4j2.xml configuration I'm using

```
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout" additivity="false"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It seems that using additivity in the root logger is a little redudant or not necesary because there is not parent for the root logger.

I'm not sure how to configure logging in order to keep all logging as debug EXCEPT some packages

Kind regards

Comment: The configuration you have should work for surpressing the log message you posted, _if_ that message is actually being logged via log4j2. However, I note that the format of the message is very different to the pattern layout in your config. This suggests you have another logging system working in parallel, and this is why you're unable to affect these messages with your log4j2 config. [Kafka appears to use slf4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.3.1), which can be configured to forward to log4j2. Which slf4j binding jars do you have on your classpath?

Comment: At least I have log4j-over-slf4j version 1.7.25 in my classpath

Comment: That allows messages logged through log4j _1_ to be routed through slf4j (i.e. a [_bridge_](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)). With SLF4J, you need a _binding_ jar that tells SLF4J what logging framework to use as its implementation. To bind to log4j2, see [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html). Also, see [here](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) for general information about setting up runtime bindings for SLF4J (the log4j2 bindings are published by log4j though, _not_ slf4j like the other bindings).

Comment: [Additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) is an attribute of the logger not the appender and yes you are correct in that there is no reason to set it on the root logger.